# Scroll two divs with one srollbar (javascript)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, scroll, position

Assume we have two divs on a page, precreated in aspx page. Both should scroll horizontally. But only one of them can have a scrollbar, the second div shouldn't have a scroll bar.

When you scroll div1 with its scrollbar, some javascript function should scroll div2 equally, i.e. set scroll position of div2 equal to scroll position of div1. It should be done absolutely simultaneously, so that user didn't see any delay between the two divs scrolling.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
/*jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".container").on("scroll", function () {
        $(".container").scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
    });
});*/


var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("container");


function foo() {
    var top = this.scrollTop;

    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].scrollTop=top;
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].addEventListener("scroll", foo);
}
```

```css
.container {

    height:400px;

    overflow-y:scroll;

    width:200px;

    background:Red;

    float:left;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="container">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</div>
    <div class="container">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</div>
</div>
```

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/pLyrqxfj/

**JS:-**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".container").on("scroll", function () {
        $(".container").scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
    });
});
```

**HTML:-**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="container">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</div>
    <div class="container">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:-**

```
.container {

    height:400px;

    overflow-y:scroll;

    width:200px;

    background:Red;

    float:left;

}
```

## EDIT:-

**Pure JavaScript:-**

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("container");


function foo() {
    var top = this.scrollTop;

    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].scrollTop=top;
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].addEventListener("scroll", foo);
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pLyrqxfj/1/)</kbd>

Comment: @SWA Please see the EDIT section. It's using pure JavaScript.

Comment: @SWA Does this answer your query?

Comment: Yeah, at some degree, I marked it as useful answer. But you actually iterate through all divs by referring to their class, which is not correct in most cases. More often you need to scroll certain divs together, not all of them, and also scroll in certain direction, not always vertically, so yes, you partially answered. I had my own answer which I figured out later..

Comment: Can use `overflow-y: hidden` on the left column to remove the middle scrollbar

Comment: One area to enhance is if the content of the two divs have different lengths, and the mouse is over the div with the shorter content, scrolling will stop for both based on the shorter content. One idea is to determine which div has the larger content and based the scrolling based on that div instead.